# ImportError: cannot import name _common

Tags: python, python-3.7, psutil

I'm facing the "ImportError: cannot import name _common" of psutil.
here is the log

> [Mon Feb 21 23:14:36.998723 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 272193:tid
> 140119627306752] [remote 127.0.0.1:35434]     import psutil

> [Mon Feb 21 23:14:36.998763 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 272193:tid 140119627306752]
> [remote 127.0.0.1:35434]   File "/home/thura/.virtualenvs/prime-new/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/**init**.py",line 40, in module

> [Mon Feb 21 23:14:36.998847 2022] [wsgi:error]
> [pid 272193:tid 140119627306752] [remote 127.0.0.1:35434]     from .
> import _common

> [Mon Feb 21 23:14:36.998920 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid
> 272193:tid 140119627306752] [remote 127.0.0.1:35434] ImportError:
> cannot import name _common

```
python: 3.7
psutil : 5.6.7
ubuntu: 20.4
```

updated

```
import psutil
def is_local_addr(ip_addr):
    ip_addr = ip_address(ip_addr)
    for interfaces in psutil.net_if_addrs().values():
        for interface in interfaces:
            if interface.family in [socket.AF_INET, socket.AF_INET6]:
                if ip_addr == ip_address(interface.address.split("%")[0]):
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: What code are you running?

Comment: @DMalan, added the function. However, the latest version of psutil has been updated and fixed.